# Fail to create array with query values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I try to save the query values into an array, but it wont become filled. The query should give something out because any values in the database accomplish the terms and the cookies have too a value. Where is my mistake?

Output:

> Array ( )

```
    $range = 'range';
  $_COOKIE["$range"];

$longitude = 'longitude';
$_COOKIE["$longitude"];
$latitude = 'latitude';
$_COOKIE["$latitude"];

$onemile = 0.005581257;
$le = $range * $onemile; 
$lo = $longitude + $le;
$loo = $longitude - $le;
$la = $latitude + $le;
$laa = $latitude - $le;


$hostname='localhost';
        $user='root';
        $password='';



                try {
                        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=loc",$user,$password);

                        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); // <== add this line
                         $sql = "SELECT id, autorid, date, longitude, latitude, title, text 
FROM post 
WHERE  (
    longitude >= $loo and longitude <= $lo
) 
OR (
    latitude >= $laa and latitude <= $la
) 
ORDER BY date";
  if ($res = $dbh->query($sql)) {

     $result = $res->fetchAll();
     print_r($result);

   }


                }
                catch(PDOException $e)
                {
                        echo $e->getMessage();
                }
```

Comment: Does the query output/execute correctly if you echo it? Separate things you should know... You should use prepared statements, you also should look at the `between` mysql function.

Comment: WHERE  (
longitude between $loo and $lo or latitude  between $laa and $la
)  doesnt change something

Comment: Yes, I said `Separate things`. First find why your query isn't working then fix the other issues. Does the query work if you output it and execute on your db?

Comment: What I'm seeing is you're storing the string 'range' to the variable $range and then multiplying it by the value of $onemile, which is 0.00558... Not sure what you expect to get.

Comment: Also a variances in latitude are a constant mileage but variances on longitude are not (they're latitude dependent). I hope I didn't say that backwards.

Comment: @chris85 I will do it tomorrow, thanks

Comment: @BisgScar it is right if e.g. range = 5 miles it will multiplied with $onemile ;)

Comment: @brabus85 But you don't set `$range` to 5, you set `$range` to the string `'range'`.

Comment: You probably meant `$range = $_COOKIE['range']`

Comment: @Barmar ok I change it but it works with latitude and longitude the same way

Comment: then I get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$longitude' (T_VARIABLE)"

Comment: None of those assignments are right. What are you expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable assignments are all wrong. They should be:

```
$range = $_COOKIE["range"];
$longitude = $_COOKIE["longitude"];
$latitude = $_COOKIE["latitude"];
```

When you try to use a non-numeric string as a number in an arithmetic expression, it's treated as `0`. So the result of your code was effectively:

```
$le = 0 * $onemile; 
$lo = 0 + $le;
$loo = 0 - $le;
$la = 0 + $le;
$laa = 0 - $le;
```

so you were setting all these variables to `0`.